# How to highlight text in SWT Combo?

Tags: java, combobox, swt

I would like to highlight a text in a combo box (`org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo`).

For example, suppose that the combo text is "IP:6061". 
I would like to highlight "IP". How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: This question is very vague at best. Are you dealing with a web application or not? Is you code external to said application or not?

Comment: What kind of combobox are we talking about? JavaFX?

Comment: You want to highlight a part of the text in a combobox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a reusable solution:

```
private void setSelection(Combo combo, String query)
{
    String comboText = combo.getText();

    int index = comboText.indexOf(query);

    if(index != -1)
        combo.setSelection(new Point(index, index + query.length()));
}
```

You could add an `else` clause to remove the selection if that's what you want to happen when there's no match in the text.

Call it like this:

```
Combo combo = ...
combo.setText("IP: 1.1.1.1");
String query = "IP";

setSelection(combo, query);
```

Answer (score 2):

To select a part of the Combo's text, use `Combo::setSelection()`

For example

```java
combo.setText( "IP:6061" );
combo.setSelection( new Point( 0, 2 ) );
```

would select the 'IP' of 'IP:6061'.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use a combination of `getSelection()` and `getText()`. But this question is very vague; so you maybe asking only to need to use `getText()` and filter the string to the characters you want.